# Type-signature vs. function equation in Haskell

Tags: types, signature, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and to functional programming.  I'm reading through Real World Haskell, and I've realized I'm confused by a few examples.

Specifically this is in Chapter 9, in the section "A Domain specific language for predicates", the examples which have the w x y z parameters.

I've boiled it down to this:

Why does this code compile?

```
f :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
f x y = x+y

main = do
  let q = f 4 5
  putStr  (show (q))
```

According to the type signature, `f` is clearly accepting 1 parameter and returning a function.
However, it seems I can write the function equation so it will accept two parameters and return an int.
Why is this possible?  Does this mean the type signature is ignored?

Is this currying?  Is this some kind of closure?
If I understand this http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying correctly, then it seems to be somewhat in reverse to currying as defined there - my `f` function is taking multiple arguments instead of a single one!

Also, can anyone answering please provide a link to some sort of Haskell documentation where this ability is stated (if possible at all).

EDIT:

After thinking about this for some time, what you two seem to be implying is that:

1) This syntax is syntactic sugar, f will always have a single parameter, no matter how many parameters are written in the equation

2) Upon application of f, the function body will (always?) be transformed into a stub (in effect, the returned function), where x is fixed to the parameter given (4), and y is a parameter.

3) Then this new function is applied to 5 which replaces y, and then the + function is evaluated.

What I was really interested in was, where exactly does it say something like "in the function equation, if you write more than one parameter, it's really syntactic sugar, and the following actually happens..." as I wrote above.
Or is that so obvious to everyone except me?

Edit II:

The real eye-opener answer was in @luqui comment below, unfortunately I don't think I can mark a comment as an answer.

It is the fact that
f x y = ...
is actually syntactic sugar for:
f = \x -> \y -> ...

And for me, everything else everyone below said follows from this.

I found a sort of source for this in the Gentle Introduction to Haskell, here: http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/tutorial/functions.html in section 3.1, called Lambda Abstractions.

> In fact, the equations:
>
> inc x                  = x+1
>     add x y                = x+y
>
> are really shorthand for:
>
> inc                    = \x   -> x+1
>     add                    = \x y -> x+y

While it doesn't use the phrase "syntactic sugar", it uses the more, uh, mathematically oriented word "shorthand", but as a programmer I read this as "sugar" :-)

Comment: Certainly not obvious, but it's something that we had to get used to pretty fast to grok Haskell.  Perhaps that's why authors forget to mention it explicitly.  Pretty sure Learn You a Haskell describes it though.

Comment: Your point #2 is a little bit off.  Once you define your function, it accepts the arguments it accepts.  When you call it as `f 4 5`, this parses as `(f 4) 5`, and so `f` is called with `4` as an argument and returns, effectively, the function `\y -> 4 + y`.  Then you have `(\y -> 4 + y) 5`, which becomes `4 + 5`, and then `9`.  The trick is that the function type and function definition are right-associative, and function application is left associative, so that they line up nicely.

Comment: @Antal s-z 
Thanks for correcting me and pointing out the symmetry between function type and function application. You could have said though "your function doesn't actually accept any arguments, it's all lambdas which are then curried".

Comment: Why is there no accepted answer to this question?

Answer (score 10):

It is currying. As the type signature says, `f` takes only one parameter. That would be `4`. It then returns a function, which is immediately applied to `5`. In fact, these two type signatures:

`Int -> Int -> Int`

and

`Int -> (Int -> Int)`

are equivalent in Haskell.

**EDIT:** this link about [Partial Application](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application), which I found inside the page you provided, explains this.

**EDIT 2:** You asked where the currying behavior of Haskell is defined. I don't know if this is what you're looking for: the [Haskell 98 Revised Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/), in section [3.3 Curried Applications and Lambda Abstractions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.3), says:

> *Function application* is written `e1 e2`. Application associates to the left, so the parentheses may be omitted in `(f x) y`.

Comment: I still don't fully understand.
I know about Int -> (Int -> Int) and Int -> Int -> Int being equivalent, but to be honest it's very confusing as well, I don't fully understand this.
What does it mean *in practical terms* ?  
Also note that I asked about the type equation, not the type signature.

The link you gave has the form of partial application I'm familiar with, taking a seemingly "normal" function with two parameters and fixing the first one in a *different* function.  However in my case it is a single function.
After thinking about it I got an idea, I'll write it below.

Comment: By type equation, I think you mean function equation. I added a link to the Haskell 98 Revised Report, I hope this helps to clarify things. Function application is left-associative, so f x y is the same as (f x) y, and f x y z is the same as ((f x) y) z, and so on. The Haskell Report calls this "curried application".

Answer (score 4):

The `->` operator is right-associative, i.e. `t -> t -> t` is the same as `t -> (t -> t)`.

If you re-write

```
f x y = x+y
```

in the equivalent form

```
f x = \y -> x + y
```

this conncetion should become obvious.

Comment: But *why* is this the equivalent form?

Comment: @Or When, it's just notation.  `f x y z = blah` is shorthand for `f = \x -> \y -> \z -> blah`.

Comment: See also [Section 4.4.3.1](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-840004.4.3.1) of the [Haskell 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) standard for the exact desugaring used to also support pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bit of currying. While I can't immediately find where in the documentation it explicitly states this behavior, all we have to do is check out our math a little about currying.

As we know, a function with the signature `Int ->(Int -> Int)` takes an `Int`, and returns a **function** that takes an `Int` and returns an Int. And we could just provide both of the `Int`s it needs to get that final int, like in your example:

```
f :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
f x y = x+y
```

And if we provide just the first argument, we get back a function that needs another argument. The bread and butter of currying.

Simply put, currying is [right-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Definition). In other words, `Int -> (Int -> Int)` is the same as `Int->Int->Int`, just we added parenthesis to make it more obvious that:

```
f 3
```

Isn't missing an argument, but actually returns a function of type `Int->Int`.

It's kind of like back in math when you learn the [associative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) of addition.

```
3 + 2 + 1 = (3 + 2) + 1 = 3 + (2 + 1)
```

The result is the same, regardless of how we put our parentheses.

Comment: What confused me wasn't the function *application*, which I'm fine with, it was the function *equation*. I just needed to see the implementation detail, f x y = .... is translated as f = \x -> \y -> .... (which *is* syntactic sugar IMO)

Comment: @Or When: Ah, ok, I misunderstood :-p

Answer (score 2):

It's not really syntax sugar, it's just how function application works in Haskell.

Consider:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
f x y z = x + y + z

g = f 4
h = g 4 5

f 4 4 5 -- 13
g 4 5   -- 13
g 6     -- 13
```

You can play with this in ghci to confirm. `g` is a partial application of function `f` - its type is `g :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

You can also write:

```
((f 4) 4) 5  -- 13
```

In this case `(f 4)` returns a partially applied function that takes two additional arguments, `((f 4) 4)` returns a partially applied function that takes one argument, and the whole expression reduces to 13.

Comment: The part "we could just provide both of the Ints..." sounds a bit like magic. How does this line up with the fact that Haskell functions accept just one argument?
Showing the actual "implementation", that is,  f x y = .... is actually f = \x -> \y -> ....  would have helped.

Comment: typo: Should be: h 6     -- 13 rather than g 6

Answer (score 2):

After thinking some more about this, I think the full explanation should be something along the lines of:

An Haskell function can only accept a single argument and return one parameter.
Haskell allows us to pretend that several arguments are passed, but this form is treated as a series of nested lambda functions.

```
f x y = x + y
```

is treated as

```
(1) f = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

This treatment is true for lambda functions as well
    \x y -> x + y
is treated as
    \x -> \y -> x + y

This allows us to treat type declaration as left-associative, that is:
    f :: Int -> Int -> Int
is actually 
    f :: (Int -> (Int -> Int))
which fits exactly to (1) above: f has no arguments, but is returning a function which accepts Int. This function in turn returns a function which accepts another Int, and returns an Int.

This means that if we want to return a function from a function, we don't have to do anything special, since that's Haskell's "default" mode.

This also means that given the type declaration
    f :: Int -> Int -> Int
We can write f's implementatin ("equation") with 0, 1 or 2 parameters.  If one or two parameter are specified, the compiler will generate the necessary lambdas to comply with the form
    f :: (Int -> (Int -> Int))

```
f = \x -> \y -> x + y

f x = \y -> x + y  -- \x -> is generated

f x y = x + y -- \x -> \y is generated
```

But in each of these cases, the function application appearing to accept two parameters will compile successfully, since it will always be translated to the first form, e.g.

```
f 4 5 --> (\x -> (\y -> x + y) 5 ) 4
```

Where the inner function application will return the curried form  (x + 5)

This enables partial function application, where we can give f just one parameter and get back a partial function.

Also, changing the precedence in the function type:

```
f'' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
```

changes the meaning - we accept a function getting an Int and returning one as the single parameter, and return an Int.
Assuming we've defined this function somewhere, then calling this function with Integer parameters, e.g.

```
f'' 4 5
```

will not compile.

Edit:

Also, even if the last arguments are in parenthesis, or are a type declaration, this holds.

E.g., in the following, the last pair of parenthesis is optional, since if they weren't there the compiler would put them anyway to get to the "lambda'd" form.

```
t4 :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
t4 f i = f i + i
```

Can be applied thus:

```
t4 (\x -> x*10) 5
```

Also, given:

```
type MyIntInt = Int -> Int
```

Then:

```
t5 :: MyIntInt -> MyIntInt
```

Is equivalent to t4, but confusing, since the meaning of MyIntInt is different in both places.
The first one is the type of the first parameter.
The second one is "expanded" into Int -> Int (probably because of the right-associativity of the operator), which means that t5 can appear to accept 0 to 2 parameters in the function equation and function application (while actually always accepting 0 and returning embedded lambdas, as I've detailed above).

E.g. we can write t5 just like t4:

```
t5 f i = f i + i
```